# Python multiprocessing: apply pool.map on methods of specific objects

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The following parallel function execution works perfectly:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randrange


def triple(number):
    return number * 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [5, 10, 20]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    print(pool.map(triple, numbers))
```

But how can I obtain the same by always calling the same method on a list of objects i.e. when the function is a method on some class of objects:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randrange


class RandomNumber():
    def __init__(self):
        self.no = randrange(100)

    def triple(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(triple(self.no))
        return triple(self.no)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # but how can I always call the same method on an object
    numbers = [RandomNumber() for m in range(0, 3)]
    # e.g. here on every random number within the list
    # call numbers[0].triple(), numbers[1].triple() ...
    # paralelly?
```

The problem is that I am bound to specific objects and cannot just use a function..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can warp this method with a function:

```
def triple_warpper(random_number: RandomNumber):
    return random_number.triple()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [RandomNumber() for m in range(0, 3)]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    print(pool.map(triple_warpper, numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `__call__` method:

```
class RandomNumber:

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r = randrange(100)
        return r

if __name__ == '__main__':

    r = RandomNumber()
    numbers = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    print(pool.map(r, numbers))
```

Comment: I accepted theletz answer because it is more generic i.e. I do not need to access the class in order to implement another method. Anyhow, thanks a lot for your answer as I hadn't known the __call__ method before!