# Parallel execution for all instances of a class in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some class:

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def method(self):
        ...
```

And a class whose attribute is a list of the previous class:

```py
class Main:
    def __init__(self, elements:list):
        self.elements : list[Example] = elements
```

Suppose I have `main = Main(elements=[example1, example2, example3])`. From the `Main` class, how can I execute the `Example` class method for all instances **without a for loop and additionally in parallel?**

Something like:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
    p.map(main.elements.method()) # Like [example1.method(), example2.method(), example3.method()]
```

For the execution of all instances [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020792) using the `getattr()` function looks good but then how can it be parallelized?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing: apply pool.map on methods of specific objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696509/python-multiprocessing-apply-pool-map-on-methods-of-specific-objects)

Comment: See also: [Multiprocessing: How to use Pool.map on a function defined in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3288595)

Comment: Yes, thanks! In fact, it is equivalent to the answer given by @Booboo. Works excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the "target" of the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` call a function that delegates to the `method` method of its passed instance reference. Then you just specify as the *iterable* argument to `map` the list of `Example` instances you wish to have method `method` called in parallel:

```py
from multiprocess import Pool

class Example:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        ...

    def method(self):
        print('method called for instance:', self.x)

class Main:
    def __init__(self, elements:list):
        self.elements : list[Example] = elements

def method_delegator(o):
    return o.method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main(elements=[Example(1), Example(2), Example(3)])
    with Pool(3) as pool:
        pool.map(method_delegator, main.elements)
```

Prints:

```None
method called for instance: 1
method called for instance: 2
method called for instance: 3
```

### Update

Or (and thanks to AKX for this) you can use function `operator.methodcaller` instead of creating a special delegator function:

```py
from multiprocess import Pool
from operator import methodcaller

class Example:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        ...

    def method(self):
        print('method called for instance:', self.x)

class Main:
    def __init__(self, elements:list):
        self.elements : list[Example] = elements

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main(elements=[Example(1), Example(2), Example(3)])
    with Pool(3) as pool:
        pool.map(methodcaller('method'), main.elements)
```

**Answer to New Question**

It probably would have been better for you to open a new question rather than piggy-back a new question on top of an old one; the two questions are not really related.

When you make a method call on an `Example` instance in a child process, a copy of the instance as it exists in the main process is created in the child process. How this is done depends on whether the *spawn* or *fork* method is used to create new processes. So unless what you are passing is sharable across processes (for example, it might reside in *shared memory* or it may be a *managed* object - see `multiprocessing.Manager` class), then any updates made by your worker function `method` is not modifying the copy that resides in the main process.

In this specific example, the easiest solution I can think of is to have `method` return the values that need to be updated on the `message` and `y` attributes and then the main process can do the actual updating of the `Element` instances. For example:

```py
from multiprocess import Pool
from operator import methodcaller

class Example:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

    def method(self):
        # Return message and y attributes to be updated by the
        # main process
        return f'method called for instance: {self.x}', None

class Main:
    def __init__(self, elements:list):
        self.elements : list[Example] = elements

if __name__ == '__main__':
    elements = [Example(1), Example(2), Example(3)]
    main = Main(elements=elements)
    with Pool(3) as pool:
        for idx, result in enumerate(pool.map(methodcaller('method'), main.elements)):
            element = elements[idx]
            element.message, element.y = result # Unpack
            print(element)
```

Prints:

```None
{'x': 1, 'message': 'method called for instance: 1', 'y': None}
{'x': 2, 'message': 'method called for instance: 2', 'y': None}
{'x': 3, 'message': 'method called for instance: 3', 'y': None}
```

Comment: (Also in the stdlib: `operator.methodcaller`)

Comment: @AKX Thanks, I have updated my answer to show that alternative.

Comment: Perfect, Booboo and @AKX. Thanks for the help, it works perfectly and actually runs faster than with a `for loop` (already verified). Thanks!

Comment: @Booboo, another related question. Suppose that instead of using `print` in the method, we have something like `self.message = f'method called for instance: {self.x}'`, and `self.y` is initialized to `None`. When I execute the method with `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` it does not update the `self.message` attribute. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: See the updated answer. It's a question of semantics, but I don't think that the new question is related to the old one; it's just the next difficulty you have encountered in what you are trying to accomplish. Only in that sense are they related.

Comment: You are right about the question and I appreciate your help. It works perfect and the execution time is practically the same. Thank you so much!